# Is there an Android Tablet equivalent of UIPopOverController?

Tags: android, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller, tablet, android-actionbar

I'm just mucking around with Android tablet stuff in 3.0.  I have fragments set up to do the equivalent of UISplitViewController for iPad.  Anyone know what the best solution to get something like the iPad UIPopOverController is?

I'm thinking the options are either a separate dialog or something in the Action Bar ...?

I haven't actually seen any Android tablets running 3.0 so not clear what the standard will be ...

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Oh I guess I should mention I am working off the Android docs on this, but noticing the docs and the demo code do slightly different things: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/optimizing-for-3.0.html

Comment: It sounds like you are asking two questions here.. Is there an equivalent of `UIPopOverController` and also what is the best place to put options in your application? Is this correct?

Comment: Hi Quintin, ah, no just the equivalent of UIPopOverController.  I use the word options to mean option 1. separate dialog and option 2. something in Action Bar.  I'm not so concerned about menu options that seem to live happily in the Action Bar.  In iOS the pop over thing appears after clicking a button in what it the equivalent of the Action Bar making me think there might be some special feature in there I had yet to find :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be exactly what you are looking for because I'm not all that familiar with `UIPopOverController` but I think you can accomplish something similar using a [`Toast`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html) with a customized layout.

I would take a look at [`Creating Toast Notifications`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) and see if it works for you.

Depending on the functionality needed it might work, otherwise you might need to look into trying to generate a modeless dialog with a custom layout.

As for your other question, yes options are generally stored in a separate activity within your application and following Honeycomb design the options activity would be accessible from the Action Bar and the options itself could be a fragment.

Comment: Thanks that's a good suggestion, although aren't toasts often useed as temporary alerts that fade out.  I think your second suggestion is probably the way to go, some sort of dialog.

Comment: @Sam Joseph Yeah unfortunately I can't really imagine something similar to what the documentation says for `UIPopOverController` so I don't have a definite alternative for Android but from what I understood it was a cross between a modeless dialog and a notification. Hope you get something working!

Answer (score 1):

Its nothing official but I would crack open the source code to the contacts app for 2.0+  They emulate the popover UI using an Activity in a pretty creative way.  It might be a little over kill as it was designed to be usable by any application not just itself. But it should help give you a nudge in the right direction.

Also depending on what the behavior you are looking for exactly a combination of fragments and action bar could be the way to go, but its not going to be as easy as iOS.

Comment: I was just having a look at the contacts app on android 3.0.  Curious that when I tried to register an email it defaulted to an exchange account.  Anyway, created a few contacts.  Couldn't see anything that looked like a popover.  I rotated to portrait and the layout was basically the same - just squeezed together.  I guess you mean the little triangle thing that has the contact pointing to the item in the list.  That does look nice, but wasn't the aspect of the popover I was looking for.  I was more interested in having the list pop-out in portrait, leaving the full screen for main content

Comment: @Sam Joseph not the 3.0 contacts app.  2.0   add a quick contact to your home screen by pressing and holding, then pick shortcuts, then contact

Comment: on IRC I was pointed to this: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13196858/Contacts.png which looks more like a popover (in a twitter client).  However I had been looking at the tablet layout.  Just forced the 3.0 emulator to have phone like dimensions, but then contacts fails to start ... weird the only default skin for level 11 AVD is WXGA

Comment: Ah, okay, now we are on the same page I hope :-) Couldn't get contact onto home screen in 2.0, but could get that popup with the four icons (like in the twitter image above) within contacts.  Visually it is similar, but I was hoping for something that would contain a complete nother view, e.g. calculator, on a large tablet screen.  Will keep digging ... thanks for your input

Comment: That's the quick action pattern. There a couple of implementations available, one is the GreenDroid library.